# Multiple NSNotifications received in parent UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I have a parent `UIViewController` `BaseViewController` that I use for some views :

```
class TestViewController: BaseViewController { ...
```

I want to receive a notification in `BaseViewController` so I add an observer in its `ViewWillAppear`:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(BaseViewController.receivedNotification(_:)), name:"NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
```

I can't remove an observer on `ViewWillDisappear` because notification is sent from presented `UIViewController` that can be presented on every `UIViewController` with parent `BaseViewController` so `BaseViewController` is always disappeared.

So after navigating through the app there is more than one observer add and I receive notification multiple times.

What should I do to perform notification selector only once? Or how to `.removeObserver` when another `UIViewController` pushed(but do not remove when presented)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can very well use:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(observer: <The class from which you want to remove>, name: "Name of notification which you want to remove", object: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can't remove an observer on ViewWillDisappear because notification is sent from presented UIViewController that can be presented on every UIViewController that parent is BaseViewController so BaseViewController is always disappeared.

You absolutely can. Each new `ViewController` that will be shown at screen will have its own instance, so its own copy of `BaseViewController`. In fact, only one copy of `BaseViewController` can be currently appeared (if we talking about fullscreen view controllers)

Comment: Yes. But when I present UIViewController all observers are removed and notification isn't received. Presented UIViewController is passcode and it's parent is not a BaseViewController.

Comment: @Roo And you don't subclass `UIViewController` from `BaseViewController`?

Comment: No. Presented `UIViewController` parent is different.

Comment: @Roo Subclass it if so. Or remove observer before you pushing, or in `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)`

Comment: @Roo by the way I found your architecture strange. Usually you do not need to catch notifications in disappeared controllers. Any view controller should have ability to refresh data/UI by get `viewWillAppear` call. Only appeared controllers don't have easy way to check changes at runtime and need notifications.

Comment: I send a notification and remove presented `UIViewController` on button click. So I get back to `UIViewController` with `BaseViewController` parent. What is the proper way to catch this event then?

Comment: @Roo check any possible changes in `viewWillAppear`. Use some data model class (singletone, probably)

Comment: I send notification in presented `UIViewController` `ViewDidDisappear` so previous `UIViewController` `ViewWillAppear` is already called and everything is ok. Thanks.